# Filtrar mês no QSqlTableModel

Tags: c++, sqlite, qt

Como que faço para filtrar o mês no `QSqlTableModel`?

Estou fazendo assim:

```
model = new QSqlTableModel(this);
model->setTable("tabela"); // db sqlite
model->setFilter("strftime('%m', campo_dataCadastro)='04'");//db YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS
model->select();
```

Mas sem sucesso. O`setFilter` é apenas para `WHERE`?

Comment: Se ta usando SQL Lite?

Comment: @FCCDias Sim, sqlite

Comment: Pelo que eu pesquisei é isso mesmo, com strftime dentro do setFilter, ele não emite erros?, Coloque mais informações tipo, a tabela dessa pesquisa, etc ...

Comment: Nenhum erro no `lastError();` Está armazenado as datas no formato `YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS`.

Comment: Tem como saber a SQL que essa classe gerou ?

Comment: `Select * From tabela WHERE strftime('%m', campo_dataCadastro)='04' ` Acho que o problema é este `select`.

Comment: Então, a SQL ta certa, eu mesmo já testei por exemplo no meu caso foi `SELECT * FROM Datas WHERE strftime('%m', Data) = '01'`, por isso que to achando estranho

Answer (score 1):

Resolvido, O problema foi o formato da data armazenada no `sqlite`.
Converte a data para `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` e funcionou o filtro.